# Sending commands to "application's shell" using "bash script"

Tags: bash

I have a program `JLinkExe` which opens it's own prompt uponn execution. So I normally run it like this:

```
JLinkExe
```

and then type the commands at it's prompt that appears:

```
J-Link>
```

There are many applications with it's own prompt and I am interested in a general method that would enable me to send commands to any kind of application that has it's own prompt.

---

I already tried two methods. They both try to send commands in this order:

1. `connect`
2. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. `erase`
7. `loadbin program.bin , 0x0`
8. `r`
9. `q`

but both fail. Here is the first method:

```
   { echo 'connect';
     echo '';
     echo '';
     echo '';
     echo '';
     echo 'erase';
     echo 'loadbin program.bin , 0x0';
     echo 'r';
     echo 'q'; } | JLinkExe
```

And the second method ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456294/gdb-in-one-command)):

```
JLinkExe <<EOF
connect




erase
loadbin program.bin , 0x0
r
q
EOF
```

I found these method on the internet but I don't understand why they fail. Especially the first one that worked in the past...

Can anyone propose any better / working / universally applicable method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because here-docs do not wait for output. Unfortunately for you I switched company, thus can't test my code below.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
expect <<-EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn JLinkExe
    expect "J-Link> " { send "connect\r" }
    expect "J-Link> " { send "\r" }
    expect "J-Link> " { send "\r" }
    expect "J-Link> " { send "\r" }
    expect "J-Link> " { send "\r" }
    expect "J-Link> " { send "erase\r" }
    expect "J-Link> " { send "loadbin program.bin , 0x0\r" }
    expect "J-Link> " { send "r\r" }
    expect "J-Link> " { send "q\r" }
    expect eof
    catch wait result
    exit [lindex \$result 3]
EOF
exit $?
```

Except waits until `J-Link>`  turns up and then sends the command through the connection.

If it doesn't work please notify me. I'll try to help you after the weekend :-)

EDIT:
A: Why did you wrap everything in `expect 2>&1 <<-EOF` and `EOF`?
*You can add `expect` in the shebang, but I often use it as part of my Bash scripts. My knowledge of Bash is better.*

B: Why a -EOF instead of EOF?
*That's because `<<-EOF` allows leading tabs when you want to end the here-doc. You can indent it in functions for instance.*

C: Why did you redirect stderr to stdout (2>&1)?
*In your case I should've removed this. I took the code from one of my other answer about expect and tailored it to your needs.*

D: What does `catch wait result` and `exit [lindex \$result 3]` do after we catch the eof?
*Nice question, I had to look this one up a little myself:*

- *`lindex` takes 4rd argument in `\$result` and exits the here-doc (0 is arg 1).*
- *`\$result` is set by `catch wait result`.*

  - *`Catch` takes the output of `wait` and puts that into `result`.*
  - *`Wait` returns four integers:*

    - *First: pid of process that's being waited on.*
    - *Second: spawn ID.*
    - *Third: -1 for errors, 0 otherwise.*
    - *Forth: Exit status of the program as set by the OS.*
- *Sources:*

  - *https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect*
  - *https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.html*
  - *https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.html*

*Note that you have to escape the `$` in the here-doc, otherwise Bash tries to process it. Hence `\$result`.*

E: Why you exit with exit $?
*Bash exits a script with the last known error code. Although you can leave it implicitly, I like to add it anyhow. It keeps the script more readable for beginners.*

Comment: I have a couple of questions. Can you elaboate on the following in your question. **A:** Why did you wrap everything in `expect 2>&1 <<-EOF` and `EOF`? **B:** Why a `-EOF` instead of `EOF`? **C:** Why did you redirect stderr to stdout (`2>&1`)? **D:** What does `catch wait result` and `exit [lindex \$result 3]` do after we catch the `eof`? **E:** Why you exit with `exit $?`?